# What language is this and what does it mean in English?

Tags: written-language, language-identification

[image: Please help identify what this means in English. I cannot read this language and cannot determine what language it is.]

Please help identify what this means in English. I cannot read this language and cannot determine what language it is.

Comment: Better check to see if this question is on-topic.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's English written in Tolkien's Tengwar, and the text is written with lots of mistakes and discrepancies, still it's obvious it is intended to be read as:

> My heart is not whole, for you hold a part of me forever.

Answer (score 4):

Looks very much like Tengwar to me, one of the writing systems developed as part of Tolkien's alternative universe. I think it's probably English, something close to the following:

/bi ihart si not kwhol, for jou hold a jart be fore mer/

But there are tons of different conventions for writing English in Tengwar, and without a large sample of text or knowing the precise convention used it's difficult to know exactly what was written. Also, it looks like the person based it partially on transliteration, when it is traditionally used more phonemically. Have a look on [Omniglot's page on Tengwar](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/tengwar.htm).

Comment: Link no longer works